# C++ how to use key word 'friend' with member functions from two classes contain with each other

Tags: c++, class, each, friend, contain

I'm new learning c++ How do I use friend with member functions from two classes contain with each other? I could not find a good answer through Google

Below is my code:

```
#ifndef FriendTest_hpp
#define FriendTest_hpp
class FriendVisitor;
class FriendTest{
    friend int FriendVisitor::getTestAdd();
private:
    int add=23;
    int  getAdd(){
        return add;
    }
public:
    void test(){
        printf("hello");
    }
    FriendTest()=default;
};

#ifndef FriendVisitor_hpp
#define FriendVisitor_hpp
#include <stdio.h>
class FriendTest;
class FriendVisitor{
    FriendTest* test;
public:
    FriendVisitor(){

    }
    int getTestAdd();
};

#endif /* FriendVisitor_hpp */
```

the IDE gives me the wrong error is :

> incomplete type 'FriendVisitor named in nested name specifier'

What is the solution?

Comment: This should work: `friend class FriendVisitor` even with incomplete type. But, you may not make `friend int FriendVisitor::getTestAdd();` as long as `FriendVisitor` is an incomplete type.

Comment: thx for answering my confusion

Comment: Your approach would work if `FriendTest.hpp` would `#include "FriendVisitor.hpp"`. (Due to this, `class FriendVisitor` would not be incomplete anymore.) But be careful concerning cyclic include dependencies - these can you drive crazy.

Comment: ok,thx for your answering again~

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
class FriendVisitor;
class FriendTest{
    friend int FriendVisitor::getTestAdd();
```

At this point in the compilation, the `FriendTest` class knows about the *existence* of the `FriendVisitor` class, but not any of its members, as its declaration is not complete.  If you reorder your code to fully declare `FriendVisitor` first, then its declaration is complete once you declare the friend function in `FriendTest` and it compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class FriendTest; // Forward declaration
class FriendVisitor{
    FriendTest* test; // Only references the class, so only forward declaration needed
public:
    FriendVisitor(){

    }
    int getTestAdd();
};

class FriendTest{
    friend int FriendVisitor::getTestAdd();  // FriendVisitor is fully declared, friend function is legal
private:
    int add=23;
    int  getAdd(){
        return add;
    }
public:
    void test(){
        printf("hello");
    }
    FriendTest()=default;
};
```

Comment: hi,thx for your answer,try for your codes ,it work! but I still have some confusion ,u mean I need declare two classes in a .h instead of two  above, is there any way declaring in two .h?

Comment: You can declare them in one header or in two separate headers, however you want, though good practice is to keep separate classes in separate headers.  I only wrote the example as I did because your example code didn't indicate they were in different files